# Parse through an array of strings to check how many times there's a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays, loops

Say I have this array of strings:

```
string[] arrayToParse = {2, G, R, G, B};
```

I need to parse through the array to check how many times is a string present so that I may end up with values like this:

```
2
GG
R
B
```

So each time the loop detects if there's another string identical, he "concatenates", then add the value to a list.

If I take another example:
`string[] arrayToParse2 = {2, Q, T, T, U, U}`
Should end up with these values:

```
2
Q
TT
UU
```

Any help anyone?

Comment: You are talking about string here or Charachters?

Comment: Strings, I know the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use LINQ (`GroupBy` method) and `string.Join`:

```
string[] arrayToParse = {"2", "G", "R", "G", "B"};

string[] results = arrayToParse.GroupBy(x => x)
                               .Select(g => string.Join(string.Empty, g))
                               .ToArray();
```

Works for both your sample inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq:

```
var stringGroups = arrayToParse.GroupBy(str => str);
```

Now you can display these groups with `String.Join`:

```
foreach(var group in stringGroups)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", group));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) approach. If it is not available or you don't want to use it, here is a longuer version (easier to understand if you've never used LINQ).

```
string[] arrayToParse = {2, G, R, G, B};
List<String> parsedList = new List<String>

foreach(String sToParse in arrayToParse)
{
  if (parsedList.Count <= 0)
     parsedList.Add(sToParse);

  else
  foreach(String sInParsedList in parsedList)
  {
     if(sToParse == sInParsedList)
        sInParsedList += sToParse;

     else
     parsedList.Add(sToParse);
  }

 string[] parsedArray = parsedList.ToArray();
```